# Miktex Compiler is not able to compile after adding some math environment

Tags: pdftex, miktex, overleaf, baposter

I was using the [baposter class](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) for making a poster for some conference. Initially, I was using the overleaf and was getting the timeout message, then I shifted to my MiKTeX compiler on my computer and there also the file did not compile.

```tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% baposter Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (11/06/13)
%
% baposter Class Created by:
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.29]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{breqn}  % Used for breaking equations on multiple lines


\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{poster}
        {
            headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
            colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
            bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
            bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
            borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
            headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
            headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
            headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
            boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
            textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
            eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
            headerheight=0.15\textheight, % Height of the header
            headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
            headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
            %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
            linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
        }
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %   TITLE SECTION 
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %
        %{\includegraphics[height=4em]{JACOBS_LOGO.jpg}} % First university/lab logo on the left
        {\includegraphics[height=4em]{IISER-K_Logo.png}}
        {\bf\textsc{Title of the poster}} % Poster title
        {\textsc{ Author Name \\  Institute \\   Department of Mathematics and Statistics}} % Author names and institution
        {\includegraphics[height=4em]{DMS-logo.jpg}} % Second university/lab logo on the right
        
        
        
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %   INTRODUCTION
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0}{
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
%       $X=\{(z,w):|z|=1,w=0\}$
        }
    \end{poster}
    
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the equation `$X=\{(z,w):|z|=1,w=0\}$`, the compiler is not able to compile and it is annoying me a lot. Kindly tell me if it the problem of the code or compiler. I am using MikTex.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `baposter.cls` come from it is not a known class from CTAN.

Comment: Note in general `breqn` is not really recommended and it does not do what the comments after it says. For now stick to the constructions from `amsmath`.

Comment: It is all down to `headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc` which is wrong, `\bf` has been depreciated since 1993!, plus `\textsc` takes an argument and we don't know it it is being given an argument is a proper manner. Use `headerfont=\Large\bfseries\scshape`

Comment: Are you sure this compiled **without** error on overleaf?

Comment: @daleif The class `baposter` is linked and after googling I knew about it. 

Yes, in overleaf it compiled without any error.

Comment: Creating a project on overleaf, adding `baposter`, removing the images I don't have, and uncommenting the math line fails for me on overleaf. The compilation never terminates. Fixing the `headerfont` line and removing `breqn` then I can also get it to compile on overleaf.